# Forcing LinuxMint Gloria to upgrade to Ubuntu Karmic

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, upgrade, linux-mint

I tried the Karmic Live CD, and it made me want the new kernel from Karmic.
It solves a couple of issues I'm having with the Jaunty/Gloria kernel (particularly display driver issues).

I tried to install the kernel deb packages from:
[http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v2.6.31.6/](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/v2.6.31.6/)

But I had issues with screen suddenly turning black, as well as being blank during startup, so I uninstalled that package and went back to normal.

Before that, I tried `do-release-upgrade -d` but it said:

```
$ do-release-upgrade -d
Checking for a new ubuntu release
No new release found
```

Apparently it's seeing the release as "Gloria", not "jaunty", and it doesn't find an upgrade for it. Where is it getting this info from? I suppose it's a text file I can edit, but which one?

Yea, I know Mint 8 will be released soon, but I also rather switch to Ubuntu for other reasons as well (and considering I already have the missing codecs/packages from the default ubuntu install).

#### EDIT:

I also tried adding karmic repositories to `/etc/apt/sources.list` and ran `sudo aptitude update`. Soon after the Update Manager popped up, did a scan, and prompted me to do a "Partial Update" because there seems to be some problems. I said ok, and it tired to update but quickly declined, saying "An upgrade from 'Gloria' to 'jaunty' is not supported with this tool."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I grepped `/etc` recursively for "Glorial", found the suspect in `/etc/lsb-release`, edited that file to say "ubuntu",

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=9.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=jaunty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 9.04"
```

and then ran the upgrade tool. Went quiet ok. It wasn't *totally* smooth (there were a few hiccups), but went mostly ok.

Though for some reason now, `/etc/lsb-release` has been edited by some 'tool' to say 'Mint' again.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is basically to migrate from one distribution to another. Mint is indeed based on Ubuntu, but it still has its own package repositories, update algorithm and such. "Upgrading" like this sounds like a potential source of many hours of pain. I'd instead copy the `home` folder to an external hard drive, clean installed Karmic on a formatted HDD and then copied the relevant directories back from the `home` folder.

Alternatively, you can try to [add the Karmic repository URIs to Synaptic](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu#Third-Party+Software+Tab) and try to do an upgrade after.

Comment: I tried adding karmic repositories. the update manager poped up but failed to install any update because "An upgrade from 'Gloria' to 'jaunty' is not supported with this tool."

Comment: And, I think mint only adds a few things like codecs, etc. It even keeps the ubuntu repositores in `/etc/apt/sources.list`, and I always update through the ubuntu Update Manager tool instead of the mintUpdate tool, and it never went wrong.

Comment: I guess the upgrade failed because an Ubuntu tool can't know how to upgrade from a third-party distribution like Gloria to Jaunty or Karmic. You'd need Mint to provide that kind of transition and thus need to wait for Mint 8.